# Code of merge sort, why there is two same while loop?

Tags: python

The following code is copy from this website
http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    print("Splitting ",alist)
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    print("Merging ",alist)

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

In the above code, there is two almost the same while loop, e.g.

```
while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
                if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                    alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                    i=i+1
```

and

```
while i < len(lefthalf):
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
                k=k+1
```

What is the reason of adding the last while loop?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OK, first, remember how merge sort works: it merges sorted sublists to create longer sorted sublists until the entire list is sorted. (The trivial case is a one-item sublist, which is by definition sorted.)

The first `while` loop takes items from the source sublists until the end of *either* is reached. At that point, there may be items still remaining in the other sublist. These items, however, are all known to be greater than (or equal to) the items in the output list. The other two `while` loops (only one of which is actually executed, because the terminating condition is already met for the other) copy these remaining items to the output list. Without these loops, you'd likely lose some items.